# Erro na requisição de reset password

Tags: php, laravel

O que eu posso fazer para corrigir o seguinte erro, que aparece quando solicito o `Reset` `Password` de usuário do sistema:

> `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Translation\Translator::getFromJson() must be of the type array, int given, called in /.../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 237`

Em nenhum desses dois arquivos eu fiz alterações e segui a configuração conforme está lá no site do `Laravel`.

Comment: Como está sendo feita a solicitação? Quais são as funções e seus códigos envolvidos no processo?

Comment: Eu não escrevi nenhum código, tudo está sendo feito pelo próprio Laravel. A única coisa que fiz foi na linha de comando, passando o comando do framework para construir a Autenticação de usuário.

Comment: Precisamos saber aonde você mudou, impossível saber somente com a exceção lançada

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que era um bug com a versão que eu baixei, a 5.7.23.

O bug foi corrigido na 5.7.24, conforme aqui: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27349